# Why is my event emitter not working on angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, output

Why is my `EventEmitter` not working?

Calling the function `sendInstruction()` the `EventEmitter` doesn't work, but testing in `ngOnInit` the event reaches on parent component, what is happening?

**child component.ts**

```
@Output() updateInstruction = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

sendInstruction() {
    this.objDetails = this.titleDetails.DetalhesTitulo
    const send: SendInstruction = {
      ...
    }
    this.service.sendInstruction(send, this.objDetails.NN_ABC).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.emitInstruction(true)
      },
      error: () => 
        ...,
    });
  }

  emitInstruction(emit){
    this.updateInstruction.emit(emit)
  }
```

**child component.html**

```
<button class="abc-button select medium col-top" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!hasInstruction || formInstructions.invalid"
        (click)="sendInstruction()">    
            Send Instruction
</button>
```

**parent component.ts**

```
getDetailsUpdate(update) {
    console.log(update);
}
```

**parent component.html**

```
<abc-instruction-billet (updateInstruction)="getDetailsUpdate($event)"></abc-instruction-billet>
```

Comment: How to import your "EventEmitter", it should be import from @angular/core.

Comment: When you call `this.service.sendInstruction` is your observable emitting any value? What does it return?

Comment: @RaheemMohamed yeah i'm already importing from @angular/core.

Comment: @Tombery The response is just a 200, calling emitInstruction() inside or outside service happens the same thing, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to your observable like this.

```
this.service.sendInstruction(send, this.objDetails.NN_ABC).subscribe(()=> {
    this.emitInstruction(true)
},error => {
    ....,
});
```

Comment: could you please show me your service "sendInstruction" function?

Comment: `sendInstruction(instruction: SendInstruction, nossoNumero: string): Observable<[]> {
    return this.http.post<AbcSuccessResponse>(`${environment.API.CHARGE}/v1/cobranca/titulo/instrucao/${nossoNumero}`, instruction)
    .pipe(map((response: AbcSuccessResponse) => response.data.Titulos, this.updateRefreshedDate())
    );
  }`

Comment: I don't think the problem is in service, calling emitInstruction() inside or outside service happens the same thing, nothing

Comment: No, the curious is if i emit the event in ngOnInit works normally, calling the emitInstruction() on button nothing happens either

Comment: why don't you check each click service call get hitting or not via the chrome network tab. and also subscribe the observable like this in your .ts file.


`this.service.sendInstruction(send, this.objDetails.NN_ABC).subscribe(res=> {
    console.log("debug the result", res)
    this.emitInstruction(true)
},error => {
    console.log("Error", error)
});`

Comment: the service is being called as well as emitInstruction, I put a log in emitInstruction and appears on console but still does not emit updateInstruction

Comment: @pedroMelo I think better to share your project with stackBlitz, then it will be easy for us to debug and resolve your issue.